Einstein live chat - how to create person accounts using pre chat form data?
I am trying to create person accounts with requirements as "a personaccount if non exists and or if it is found it links the personcontact to the transcript and the personaccount as well, enabling chat history"
this is the code 
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{

            "label":"First Name",  

            "transcriptFields": ["FirstName__c"]

        },{

            "label":"Last Name", 

            "transcriptFields": ["LastName__c"]

        },{

            "label":"Email", 

            "transcriptFields": ["Email__c"]

        }

        ];

        embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{

            "entityName": "Contact",

            "saveToTranscript": "ContactId",

            "showOnCreate": true,

            "entityFieldMaps": [{

                "isExactMatch": false,

                "fieldName": "FirstName",

                "doCreate": false,

                "doFind": false,

                "label": "First Name"

            }, {

                "isExactMatch": false,

                "fieldName": "LastName",

                "doCreate": false,

                "doFind": false,

                "label": "Last Name"

            }, {

                "isExactMatch": true,

                "fieldName": "Email",

                "doCreate": false,

                "doFind": true,

                "label": "Email"

            }]

          },

          {

            "entityName": "Account",

            "showOnCreate": true,

            "linkToEntityField": "AccountId",

            "saveToTranscript": "AccountId",

            "entityFieldMaps": [

                {

                    "isExactMatch": false,

                    "fieldName": "LastName",

                    "doCreate": true,

                    "doFind": false,

                    "label": "Last Name"

                },

                {

                    "isExactMatch": true,

                    "fieldName": "RecordTypeId",

                    "doCreate": true,

                    "doFind": false,

                    "label": "Account Record Type",

                    "value": "012xxxxxxxxxxx",

                },

                {

                    "fieldName": "PersonEmail",

                    "doCreate": true,

                    "label": "Email"

                }

              ]

          }

          ];

and running the using the managed package flow to get the customer context when a bot is initialized

with the above code , the flow is being called successfully but the output is always null and hence no person account is being created.
Has anyone faced the same situation ?
Please advice
thanks
